NavigationStack -> navigationDestination infinite loop
In a project where each view has a ViewModel object that I was using in my .navigationDestination(...). Caused an infinite loop sometimes, not every time.
This code is causing infinite loop navigationDestination was called infinite times but the problem wasn't navigationPath, on every iteration if we check navigationPath it contains correct values
@State var viewModel: ViewModel

var body: some View {
    Text("Some View")
        .navigationDestination(for: Routing.self) { route in
            switch route {
                case .showMap:
                    MapView(viewModel.someValue)
            }
        }
}

this code works fine when we are not using viewmodel in navigationDestination block
@State var viewModel: ViewModel

var body: some View {
    Text("Some View")
        .navigationDestination(for: Routing.self) { route in
            switch route {
                case .showMap(let someValue):
                    MapView(someValue)
            }
        }
}

the result is that if i'm using viewmodel in navigationDestination in same cases (not every time) it causes infinite loop
ps viewModels are @Observables so all the viewModels are @State.
I was trying to navigate from one view to another and at some point on a random screen i get infinite loop.

Please add the navigation call and extend the View in you question with the wrapping structs.

This is pseudo code to express what I'm doing and what's the problem is, in the whole project things are like that and on a random screen I got that problem in this case the actual looks like this
.navigationDestination(for: SignUpMethodRoutes.self) { route in
viewModel.coordinator.buildScene(for: route)
}
which causes infinite loop but if i create simple Text() like this
.navigationDestination(for: SignUpMethodRoutes.self) { route in
Text("Example")
}
it works fine

What is ViewModel? You probably don't want it to be @State.

ViewModel is @Observable so as apple documentation states all @Observables should be @State and not @ObservedObject or @StateObject anymore

@State var viewModel: ViewModel
Should always be private

@2dnas if you provide a minimal product to reproduce this i can take a look. Without you sharing more information than in your question i cannot say what the issue is.

Show a minimal code, see: Minimal code.
In your view, you should declare @State private var viewModel = ViewModel().
If you pass it from a parrent view, then use .environment(viewModel) in the parent view
and @Environment(ViewModel.self) private var viewModel in the child view.
See Managing model data in your app.
Note that for navigationDestination to work, you need a NavigationStack
in the code you don't show.

Thank you guys for your support, the problem absolutely makes no sense in the View there was variable @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss which causes this infinite loop if you have .navigationDestination(Something.self) { ...  } this and  @Environment(.dismiss) var dismiss` causes this effect. i was debugging like 3 hour and I commented nearly everything in the view to find the root cause for this problem and at a later point this variable wasn't even used in the View.

After that I tried that on another View and get same result if there is  @Environment(.dismiss) var dismiss and .navigationDestination(for: SignUpMethodsRoutes.self) in the same view causes infinite loop even if you don't use dismiss() which absolutely makes no sense

I also tried that on fresh project with simple two screen and there wasn't problem, I think there could be some side parent class or something which doesn't working properly in the project but still can't understand how can just instantiating a variable in view cause something like that.

You never show any code or mention the problem with dismiss in your question,
that is why you need to show a minimal code that produces your issue, see: Minimal code. A complete (minimal) example that we can compile and run, that include the NavigationStack part.

Everyone in here complaining about not enough code is flat out wrong. Simply put a NavigationLInk in a NavigationStack with an @Environment(.dismiss) and you will get an endless loop.
